# How does absolute value affect limits?

Tags: limits, analysis

When an absolute value appears in a limit, I can’t figure out in which way it affects the limit.

I know that the limit of the absolute value of a function is the absolute value of a limit, but what should I do when the absolute value is inside the function, and not affecting the whole function?
It is not a problem for me to figure it out in a one variable limit, but when working with two or more variables I don’t know what to do.

Here’s an example of a limit I would struggle with: $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0, 0)} f(x)$

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$,} \\[0.5em]
\displaystyle \frac{x \left| y \right|^p}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.}
\end{cases} $$

Can anyone give some advice on what to do with that absolute value and how it affects the way you solve the limit?

Comment: You could convert to polar coordinates

Comment: tIt wouldn't affect the way I took the limit. In this problem I suspect it's there just so everything stays real. The limit, if it exists, must be zero, seen by considering the path with $x=0$. So I would either prove the limit is zero using the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition, or show it doesn't exist by considering some path on which the limit isn't zero.

Comment: I see you've asked 8 questions but have never accepted an answer. Were none of them sufficient or did you not know that as the poster you can accept an answer?

Comment: I did not know you could accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $p>0$. Then

$$
\left| {\frac{{x\left| y \right|^p }}{{\sqrt {x^2  + y^2 } }}} \right| = \frac{{\left| x \right|}}{{\sqrt {x^2  + y^2 } }}\left| y \right|^p  = \sqrt {\frac{{x^2 }}{{x^2  + y^2 }}} \left| y \right|^p 
$$
But
$$
0 \le \sqrt {\frac{{x^2 }}{{x^2  + y^2 }}}  \leq 1\,\,\,\,\,\forall \left( {x,y} \right) \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \left\{ {\left( {0,0} \right)} \right\}
$$
Therefore, since $
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \left| y \right|^p  = 0
$.
you have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \sqrt {\frac{{x^2 }}{{x^2  + y^2 }}} \left| y \right|^p  = 0
$$
because the first factor in bounded. Hence

$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \left| {\frac{{x\left| y \right|^p }}{{\sqrt {x^2  + y^2 } }}} \right| = 0
$$
so that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \frac{{x\left| y \right|^p }}{{\sqrt {x^2  + y^2 } }} = 0
$$
If $p< 0$ by using the restriction $y=x$ it follows that the limit does not exists, because you get

$
f(x) = \frac{{x\left| x \right|^p }}{{\sqrt {x^2  + x^2 } }} = \frac{x}{{\sqrt{2}\left| x \right|}}\frac{1}{{\left| x \right|^{\left| p \right|} }}
$
and
$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ +  } f(x) =  + \infty 
$
while
$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ -  } f(x) =  - \infty 
$
If $p=0$ you get again that the limit does not exists by considering the restriction $y=0$ and taking the limit of the function in one variable that you get.

Comment: Thank you very much to point out my misprints.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value has no effect here because, in order to show that the limit is zero, it is sufficient to bound
$$
\left|\dfrac{x|y|^p}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0 \right|
$$

by some function with zero limit. Using the inequality $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, you can see that
$$
\left|\dfrac{x|y|^p}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0 \right| \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|y|^p}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = |y|^p \to 0\quad  ((x,y) \to (0,0)),\qquad p>0.
$$

When $p=0$, using the directional limits
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+\\y=mx}f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}},
$$

we see that the limit does not exist. The same goes for $p<0$

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+\\y=mx}f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{x|mx|^p}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} = \dfrac{m^p}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^p = \infty.
$$